# How to change the language of Xtrareport

Tags: localization, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm using XtraReport and its wonderful, but I'm having a little problem.

I want change the language of report before printing, because I want use Indian Numbers in my report instead of En-Numbers.

I try to change the current language of the thread but nothing happens:

```
CultureInfo arabicCI = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = arabicCI;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = arabicCI;

arabicCI.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = 
    DigitShapes.NativeNational;
```

I also tried:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("SA");

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Since this question is highly ranked on Google and the two deleted answers provide useful links IMHO, I repeat them here: "[Q472742 - XtraReports Localization](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q472742)" and "[Q284383 - How I can override the GetPrintableControls method from inside my XtraReport class?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q284383)".